# Tab Stops in Text Editor & Default Word Wrapping

Tags: macos, text-editor

I have noticed in several applications that there appears to be some sort of implicit line width which causes text to wrap.

For example, suppose I type in the following:

```
12345678901234567890123456789012    etc
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
```

(there is a `tab` between numbers on the second line, and before the `etc`).

*Many* text editors end up wrapping as follows:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901
    etc
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
    14
```

which suggests some sort of implicit limit at 31 characters.

I have seen this in unrelated applications, such as MacDown and SQLPro and many others which I would regard as light duty from the text processing point of view.

Heavier duty text editors such as Atom don’t do this, which would suggest that the others use some sort of native text editor which implements this behaviour.

Is there any way of convincing the text editor not to jump to the next line when tabbing past 31 characters?

Comment: Does the wrapping position change if you change the width of the window

Comment: @Mark No. If I make it too narrow, it simply gets lost.

Comment: What if you make it wider?

Comment: @Mark Same. The behaviour is independent of the window width. It is also the same if I change the font size.

Comment: What are the tab stops in the editor? and the lines are 50 characters where does 31 come from?